# I need help to run 1 million concurrent user on trading application using jmeter or other tool

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, blazemeter, threadgroup

I am looking for a tool that allow us to run 1 million concurrent user in a trading site in 1 second.

I had tried using Jmeter, created script using Blaze meter and run this script using Jmeter but unable to run it using this tool.

Comment: This question could end up being opionion based - let's see. I used jmeter, gatling and locust.io and found all of them to be somewhat limited

Comment: How many concurrent users you succeeded? what happened after you are above that maximum?

Answer (score 1):

Check this article if you haven't, it gives you good information that you could answer your own question.

[What’s the Max Number of Users You Can Test on JMeter?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what%E2%80%99s-the-max-number-of-users-you-can-test-on-jmeter/)

**From the article:**

> JMeter limits depend on the capabilities of your machine and network, the complexity of your performance scripts, the targeted number of simulated users and so forth.